# Set the frame before, and after currently selected keyframe to 0 automatically?

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys

As title says.

Since blender cant do corrective shapekeys without the tedious process of setting up drivers, it would actually be quicker for me to just sculpt in the fix per frame in most cases.

Example: Say I have a Knee bending for around 8 frames of animation.

Would it be possible to make a shapekey, have prior / next frames set to 0 automatically while the frame im on set to 1, sculpt the fix, then move on to the next frame.. etc etc.

So for every shapekey I make, the value would be 0 - 1 - 0.

It would be such a time saver and unless theres an easier way to just sculpt in in-betweens, this is what I do.